# Make npm install faster

Tags: npm, npm-install

An average npm install seems to take around 44 seconds on my machine for a new Angular project, when created using the Angular CLI.

I looked at the usage of the computer resources but I didn't see anything being used at 100% (CPU, RAM, Disk, Ethernet).

Is the install time that **'slow'** due to the response times of the requests made during the process, or the speed of the server that feeds me the node modules or is there a specific hardware component that is slowing down the process?

Basically, I want to know if upgrading something on my computer could decrease the install time.

Comment: I want to know too.

Comment: On an existing project and relatively new version of npm, you can use `npm ci`